# How i dismiss keyboard on tapping search button on keyboard regarding UISearchBar?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ipod

I m developing an application in which i adding one control UISearchBar. When i started editing text in UIsearchBar then keypad is animated on the screen. After i completed my complete editing or canceling all text then i will stuck on point of dismissing keypad. 
How i dismiss keyboard on tapping search key form UIKeypad?

Also same question for UITextField and UITextView?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure the view controller which has the SearchBar implements the SearchBarDelegate and you set the searchBar.delegate to self:

```
@interface AddressSearchViewController : UIViewController <UISearchBarDelegate>
```

then implement the following method:

```
-(void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}
```

This will make the keyboard disappear when you tap the search button on the keyboard or the search bar

Comment: Thanks, now my code working. Your answer are really very descriptive.

Answer (score 3):

For the search bar:

```
- (void)searchBarTextDidEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
   [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}
```

And same thing for the text field:

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: ,your answer still not worked for me. i want dismiss keyboard using tabbing search key which is already standard UI of keyboard.

Comment: It should work with the first one. Is the view controller the search bar's delegate? `searchBar.delegate = self;`

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in ViewDidLoad

```
-(void) ViewDidLoad
 {
    [super ........];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(hideKeyboard)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
    gestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;    
 }

 - (void) hideKeyboard 
 {
    [texfieldname1 resignFirstResponder];
    [texfieldname2 resignFirstResponder];
 }
```

Comment: i want dismiss keyboard using tabbing search key which is already standard UI of keyboard.