# resignFirstResponder for UITextField with search returnkey

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Simple question: how can I resign my textfield if my "done" key is Search. Essentially, what do I do if the user does not want to search, but instead wants to cancel...

thanks

Comment: Put a bar button in the navigation bar, which hides the keyboard by just resigning the first responder.

Comment: same question like this:-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8558339/how-i-dismiss-keyboard-on-tapping-search-button-on-keyboard-regarding-uisearchba

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use: a cancel button for SearchBar and need to implement this `SearchBar delegate` :

```
- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    isSearching = NO; //This is a flag which specifies if searching is going on or not.
    searchBar.text = @""; //Clears out search bar text
    [self resetSearch]; //Reset search resets all the flags and variables.
    [self.leadsTable reloadData]; //Reloads the tableView
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder]; //Resigns responder from Search bar
}
```

This is a proper way to resign the responder if user doesn't want to search.

Look at how you can add an in-built Cancel button in UISearchBar. Check the property "**Shows Cancel Button**" (Red Arrow highlight)

[image]

**EDIT:**

**STEP-1:**
Check conditionally whether your textField's text is blank? If so resignFirstResponder for the TextField. You need to set the Delegate to `self` for the UITextField using code:

```
txtField.delegate = self;
```

Or you can do the same from the interface builder by connecting TextField's `delegate` to `File's Owner`.

**STEP-2:** You need to implement this delegate method.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
   if([textField.text isEqualToString:@""])
   {
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
   }
    return YES;
}
```

**EDIT-1:**

Now create a UIToolbar with one bar button labeled 'Cancel'

Once you have done that:

You can write an button click event for UIToolBar:

```
-(IBAction)cancelClicked:(id)sender
{
    [txtField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Once you have done that you can now just write:

```
txtField.inputAccessoryView = toolbarOutlet;
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: this is not what I'm looking for as the textField is inside of a UITableView cell, not a UISearchBar. Thank you for your answer though.

Comment: @derek.lo: Any specific reason to have a UITextField and not a UISearch bar under a UITableViewCell?

Comment: The textfield is not meant to search through results in a tableview, it is meant to send a request for an item in DB. Therefore it just looks better in a cell.

Comment: Then why do you show a search button in keyboard when you have your textField in focus and keyboard is being appeared?

Comment: @derek.lo: Please do check **EDIT** section of my answer. I have edited my answer and made it more feasible as in your case you have a `UITextField` and not a `UISearchBar`.

Comment: it would be most helpful if you could go over this: Use the inputAccessoryView of the text field to display a separate cancel button in a toolbar above the keyboard.

Comment: @derek.lo oh yes, Refer to **Ermiar**'s answer in my link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5591792/how-to-get-keyboard-with-next-previous-and-done-button

Comment: @derek.lo: Please refer to **EDIT-1** section of my code to get an idea on how to use `inputAccessoryView` to attach a UIToolbar with Cancel button.

Comment: this is clearly now the best answer. Thanks for your advice and time

Answer (score 1):

The text on the return button is irrelevant to the discussion. You want to know how to resign first responder without pressing the return button, and there are a few ways to do it.

1. Use the `inputAccessoryView` of the text field to display a separate cancel button in a toolbar above the keyboard.
2. Use a tap gesture recognizer on the field's superview to recognize when the user taps outside the field, and call `[self.view endEditing:YES]` (where `self` is your view controller). This will cause the first responder to resign. (This is very finicky in a scroll view.)
3. Swap out the `rightBarButtonItem` of the current view controller for a cancel bar button item while editing, assuming you have a `UINavigationBar` on screen at the time. When editing ends, swap back in the regular right bar button item, if any.

Comment: Yup, this is what I needed to know. Thanks @warrenm