# UISearchbar keyboard search button Action

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uisearchbar, keyboard-events

I'm using `UISearchBar` when I input text on `UISearchBar` the keyboard shows. At that time, keyboard return key is "Search".
I want to implement event when I press the keyboard search button.
How can I implement the action?
On `UITextField` it has

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField;
```

But on `UISearchBar` it doesn't have return action.

Thank you for your helping.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How i dismiss keyboard on tapping search button on keyboard regarding UISearchBar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8558339/how-i-dismiss-keyboard-on-tapping-search-button-on-keyboard-regarding-uisearchba)

Answer (score 130, accepted):

**Add UISearchBarDelegate in .h**

**Also set SearchBar's object delegate to self.**

Add this to the UISearchBarDelegate's method:

```
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
    // Do the search...
}
```

**Swift**

```
func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

Answer (score 24):

**In Swift 3:**

```
 func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
 }
```

Answer (score 6):

The `textFieldShouldReturn` method is a `textField` delegate method and not the one you're looking for. What you need is a `UISearchBarDelegate` method called `searchButtonClicked`, [have a look here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISearchBarDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007530-CH3-SW8).

Answer (score 0):

i Used following code in swift 5. implement  UISearchBarDelegate   then write following  code   in class keyboard will automatically hide on clicking search

```
class sample: UIViewController, UISearchBarDelegate {

    let searchbar:  UISearchBar = {
        let sear = UISearchBar()
        sear.tintColor = Mycolor().lightgray1
        sear.backgroundColor = Mycolor().lightgray1
        sear.barTintColor =  Mycolor().lightgray1
        sear.placeholder = "Search Asset"
        sear.layer.cornerRadius = 30
        sear.barStyle = .default
        sear.backgroundImage = UIImage()

        sear.returnKeyType = .search

        // sear.addShadow(offset: CGSize(width: 10, height: 10), color: UIColor.darkGray, radius: 20, opacity: 5)

        return sear

    }()

    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    }
}
```