# Use UISearchController without storyboard

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchcontroller

I am relatively new to iOS (100 hours or so) and I am trying to implement a UISearchController without a storyboard.  Is it possible to do this programmatically?

Comment: Additionally to Praveens detailled answer, if you need Objective-C examples, Apple provided [example code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/TableSearch_UISearchController/Introduction/Intro.html) for dealing with UISearchController in iOS8.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to implement `UISearchController` programmatically since Apple hasn't provided the ability to set it up using Storyboard yet.

Here are the steps to implement `UISearchController` in a view controller

- Conform to `UISearchResultsUpdating` Protocol
- Create a variable to reference the `UISearchController`

  ```
  var searchController: UISearchController!
  ```
- Set `searchController` in `viewDidLoad(_:)`

  ```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

      searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

      // The object responsible for updating the contents of the search results controller.
      searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self

      // Determines whether the underlying content is dimmed during a search.
      // if we are presenting the display results in the same view, this should be false
      searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false

      // Make sure the that the search bar is visible within the navigation bar.
      searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()

      // Include the search controller's search bar within the table's header view.
      tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar

      definesPresentationContext = true
  }
  ```
- Implement the method `updateSearchResultsForSearchController(_:)`, which is called when the search bar becomes the first responder or when the user makes changes to the text inside the search bar

  ```
  func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
      // No need to update anything if we're being dismissed.
      if !searchController.active {
          return
      }

      // you can access the text in the search bar as below
      filterString = searchController.searchBar.text

      // write some code to filter the data provided to your tableview
  }
  ```

Comment: Perfect, if only you can add the delegate methods for UISearchBar to your answer to avoid confusions with managing the search bar, it would be just great. They are referenced at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17628326/1953178. Thanks!

Comment: What is tableView?